# webpack index file can't find static folder

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently using the webpack-vue template to build my application (link: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), but I'm facing some problems.

Since I need to integrate my build with a back-end framework (probably php-laravel) I wanted to test the bundle. The problem is that the file static/index.html generated by webpack itself throws some errors:

```
index.html:1 GET file:///static/css/app.96d14fbf18e5bfb68fd0f9edce92c47a.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 GET file:///static/js/manifest.a4398cfdc7137ae839bb.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 GET file:///static/js/vendor.e9845cb55d3e0c57edf6.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 GET file:///static/js/app.436c8ff4536e93d010e6.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It's enough to change the /static to ./static to solve this but I don't understand why webpack can't figure it out by itself.
This is my config/index.js file:

```
var path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    build: {
        env: require("./prod.env"),
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"),
        assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        assetsSubDirectory: "static",
        assetsPublicPath: "/",
        productionSourceMap: true,
        // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
        // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
        // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
        // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
        productionGzip: false,
        productionGzipExtensions: ["js", "css"],
        // Run the build command with an extra argument to
        // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
        // `npm run build --report`
        // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
        bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
    },
    dev: {
        env: require("./dev.env"),
        port: 8081,
        autoOpenBrowser: true,
        assetsSubDirectory: "static",
        assetsPublicPath: "./",
        proxyTable: {},
        // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
        // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
        // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
        // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
        // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
        cssSourceMap: false
    }
}
```

Where can the problem be? I haven't touched that file (but the port number from 8080 to 8081)...

Comment: It looks like you're double clicking the HTML instead of opening it via a server? That won't work. webpack removes the need to run a node server, but you still need a web server.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but how can I integrate it with a back-end application then? Because it will work as a monolitic app, not front-end -> api <- back-end

Comment: In your `package.json` you add a `homepage` param, like `"homepage": "/laraval-app"`. The paths are now adjusted so the build will work from `htdocs/laravel-app` i.e. `http://[server]/laravel-app`